# How can I have iframe and div side by side when iframe is display:block;

Tags: html, css, iframe

I need to align iframe and div side by side. The problem is the iframe disapear when I add `display:inline-block;`
This is the video / iframe styles that are already set.

```
.video-container {
    max-width: 620px;
}

.video {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    background-color: #000;
}

.video iframe {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I've tried to add them into a wrapper and make the wrapper `relative` and the side div `absolute`, but can't make it work.
It all have to be responsive but I can manage that part myself, just need help making them side by side and preferably both `relative`.

Heres a codepen link with what I'm trying to accomplish:
https://codepen.io/Volcan3/pen/PmbYKz

Comment: can you supply the markup you're using, even just for this section? Your link didn't seem to link

Comment: @JesseEarley ooh, realy sorry about that. heres the link I tried to add codepen.io/Volcan3/pen/PmbYKz

Comment: Is your markup for this side div missing? I'm not seeing it in your codepen :)

Comment: @JesseEarley Sorry, I'm not sure how to ask the question properly so it can be a little confusing. The div I'm mentioning in the question is supposed to be in the grey erea beside the video. So the html code would technically be right under (or above) the `.video-wrapper` class. But because of how I plan on making it look for phones and smaller screens I have not yet added it. 

If any of that made any sense.

Comment: @JesseEarley I have updated the codepen too with aittle text and the div where I think it needs to be, but I have not given it any css (nor content) because I have no clue how to make it how I want without giving the `.video-wrapper` `display:inlin-block;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're aiming for?
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QvdymL

```
   * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.video-container {
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
}

.video {
   position: relative;
   padding-bottom: 56.25%;
   background-color: #000;
   height: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   max-width: 100%;
}

.video iframe{
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}

.side-div{
   background: blue;
   color: #fff;
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
}


.wrapper {
   width:100%;
   background-color:#CCC;
}

.wrapper-top {
   width:100%;
   height:60px;
   background-color:#000;
}

.wrapper-bottom {
   width:100%;
   height:40px;
   background-color:#000;
   clear: both
}
```

Comment: Not exactly, removing or changing the style from the class's `.video-...` will make the iframe not resize how its supposed to, pluss this will have a impact on the content bellow the whole video thing.

what I'm realy aiming for is something like how twitch.tv, or youtube.com does it. with a resizeable ifram (styles provided), and then have some content right next to it. While the "black bars" at the top and bottom are just placeholders for information about the video.

Comment: I've updated the styles, is this what you're shooting for?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I'm looking for, thank you so much for your help :)